# Getting Started with OpenCL with NVIDIA graphics cards and Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opencl, nvidia

I am looking to start programming using OpenCL. I currently have a laptop running Ubuntu Linux. (More specifically it's Linux Mint however they are similar in many respects and I will be changing back to Xubuntu shortly, so I am hoping any info will work for both.)

This laptop is a "difficult" laptop because it has both an on-chip Intel graphics processor (side by side with the CPU) and a dedicated NVIDIA Graphics Card. (I believe it is a GTX 670?) I say difficult because it was pretty complicated to install the drivers to allow me to develop using OpenGL... Even now I get confused sometimes when I run my program and it explodes because I didn't run it using 'optirun'.

Anyway, back to the question in hand, I researched the required software, and continually keep being pointed at NVIDIA's site to download their OpenCL drivers / toolkits. However I would prefer to use Khronos OpenCL rather than NVIDIA's Cuda. I don't fully understand what the difference is however*, and online info is either limited or cryptic.

The actual programming / problem vectorization I have already done, I'm just a bit lost at the moment as to what software I should / must install and how to go about doing so.

*Edit: I find the OpenCL syntax more intuitive.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Khronos OpenCL", Khronos only holds the specifications, not the implementations. NVIDIA ships their OpenCL SDK within the CUDA SDK I believe (or as separate downloads in the OpenCL sample page, I think).

Comment: The easiest way is to install NVIDIA CUDA SDK; it contains OpenCL header files and ICD. As an alternative, you can download header files and ICD source files from Khronos repository, and build ICD yourself. In fact you can just as well install OpenCL SDK from AMD (called AMD APP SDK) - it contains the exact same header and library files (a newer version, to be precise) which you include in your project and link against. Those are just a "proxy" to an actual OpenCL runtime which comes as part of the vendor-supplied drivers.

Comment: This Q/A may also be of relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526984/many-opencl-sdks-which-of-them-i-should-choose. Where its author is incorrect though (in my opinion), is when he states platform-specific extensions come from the SDK - in fact they are part of standard headers provided by Khronos.